# JWT bearer authentication and Dependency Injection with Identity inside ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm migrating an MVC3 webapi to aspnetcore and I'm having difficulty replicating the same functioning of the jwt token validation procedure.

Due to the way the application is structured, the JWT tokens do not expire but can be revoked by the server. To achieve this we used Identity and EntityFramework6 with a customized `UserManager` by us to be able to manage the tokens (a bit like it is now done by default with EFCore).

After verifying the token, let's check the database if the token is present. If not, the authentication procedure fails. This, in the old application, was executed  this piece of code:

```
public class JwtBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        await base.ValidateIdentity(context);
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<CustomUserManager>();
        var userTokens = await userManager.GetTokensAsync(context.Ticket.Identity.GetUserId(), JwtConstants.TokenType);
        var ticketId = context.Ticket.Identity.GetClaim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti);
        if (!userTokens.Any(x => x.Name == ticketId))
            context.Rejected();
    }
}
```

Obviously, in the new version of the application this thing doesn't work anymore and so I investigated how to get the same functionality. While exploring the documentation I found that the `AddJwtBearer()` command available in the `ConfigureServices` method supports adding custom `SecurityTokenValidators` and thought about using them to replicate the function.

My problem at this point is, how can I use Dependency Injection to retrieve my UserManager (or Entity context) in order to replicate the functionality of the old application?

Note: this is how I configured the EFCore context, the UserManager and the JwtBearer:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // add db context
   services.AddDbContext<CustomDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
   
   services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, CustomRole>(options => 
   {
      ...
   })
   .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>();

   services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),

                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSettings:SigningKey"])),
                };

                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
                options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new CustomJwtValidator());
            })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would first add your CustomerUserManager and CustomDbContext as constructor parameters to CustomJwtValidator and then add CustomJwtValidator to the DI pipeline like this:

```
services.AddScoped<CustomJwtValidator>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then I would add the SecurityTokenValidator like this:

```
options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(serviceProvider.GetService<CustomerJwtValidator>());
```

Side note: you will get a compiler warning stating that singleton instances will be created more than once when you call BuildServiceProvider

Comment: What abount using a scoped `IPostConfigureOptions<T>`?